# How do I execute .AppImage files using regular expressions in bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to execute a .AppImage program using regular expressions because the .AppImage updates it's name every time I update it.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

./home/myname/Applications/myApplication-*.AppImage
```

Output:

```
./launch_myApplication.sh: line 3: ./home/myname/Applications/myApplication-*.AppImage: No such file or directory
```

The real .AppImage name is "myApplication-2-11-2.AppImage", but as written above: the verison number changes every update.

How do I execute .AppImage files using regular expressions in bash scripts?

Comment: What's your current directory? `./home/myname` usually isn't a valid path, unless your current working directory is `/`.

Comment: ...to use an absolute path instead of a relative one, change `./home/myname` to just `/home/myname`, removing the leading `.`

Comment: Mind, it's bad form to assume there will be one and only one match. Better would be to write code to actually check that before proceeding.

Comment: You should actually be able to execute the application using a wildcard.  You probably have an issue your path like Charles is saying...

Comment: Also, think about using the `exec` builtin any time you're starting a different program from the last line of a script. It's a little more efficient, but the big advantage is that the target program inherits the PID of the shell for easier signaling.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The script is located in the same directory as the .AppImage file. Even if i try using a relative path (`./myApplication.AppImage`) I get the same error (`./launch_myApplication.sh: line 3: ./myApplication-*.AppImage: No such file or directory`)

Comment: @Nqtural, you **already are** using a relative path. `./home` is relative; it would need to be `/home` without the `.` to be absolute. So saying "even if I try" -- you were already trying to use a relative path, and it was already failing, before you asked the question; _that's what's wrong_.

Comment: @Nqtural, that said, you might find the following instructive: `set -- ./*.AppImage; printf '%q\n' "$@"`; compare to what you get if instead of `./*.AppImage` you use `/home/yourself/Applications/*.AppImage` or `./home/yourself/Applications/*.AppImage`.

Comment: Once you have the above printing the right thing, then replace `printf '%q\n' "$@"` with `"$1"`. Better yet, sanity-check `$#` first and fail gracefully with a nice error message when its value isn't `1`, and when `$1` doesn't exist.

Comment: (once you've got the immediate problem solved you'll want to store the list of candidate names in an array to leave `"$@"` unmodified so it can be used to pass through command-line arguments, but best to do one thing at a time).

Comment: By the way, what you're using here isn't a regular expression at all; it's a glob expression, also known as a fnmatch expression. In regex, `.` is a single-character wildcard, and `*` means "zero or more of the prior thing"; in a glob, `?` is a single-character wildcard, and `*` means "zero or more of anything".

Comment: @Nqtural Relative paths are resolved based on the process's working directory, not the location of a script. A script inherits its working directory from whatever ran the script. If you want the script to locate an AppImage from a script in the same directory, you need to either 1) supply an absolute path to the directory, or 2) have the script figure out its own absolute path, which is nontrivial (see [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)).

Answer (score 0):

#### run in relative path

```bash
cd YOUR-TARGET-DIRECTORY

# save the name in cmd
cmd=$(echo myApplication-*.AppImage)

# run it
./$cmd
```

#### run in absolute path

```bash
cmd=$(echo /home/myname/Applications/myApplication-*.AppImage)

# WRONG
#./$cmd

# CORRECT
$cmd
```

#### safer

```bash
#!/bin/bash

filename='/home/myname/Applications/myApplication-*.AppImage';

if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then
    $filename;
else
    echo "$filename not found";
fi
```

#### NOTE

if your `$HOME` is `/home/myname` you need to update your script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# wrong
# ./home/myname/Applications/myApplication-*.AppImage

# right
/home/myname/Applications/myApplication-*.AppImage
```